# Derivative of a dot product with respect to vector

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

I'd like to get the derivative of the following expression, 
$$A=\vec{r_1} \cdot \vec{r_2} $$ with respect to $\vec{r_2 }$ where $\vec{r_1}$ is constant. 
$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial \vec{r_2}}=\vec{r_1} \cdot  \frac{\partial \vec{r_2}}{\partial \vec{r_2}}$$
So, Will this be equivalent to the following ? 
$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial \vec{r_2}}= I \: \vec{r_1}$$
where I is the identity matrix

Comment: That's what it *would* be, assuming it made sense to divide by a vector. How do you define this?

Comment: This is is not a division by a vector, this is a derivative with respect to a vector which will result an identity matrix.

Comment: How do you divide by a vector differential if you can't divide by vectors?